# Azure App Configuration from Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-app-configuration

I am accessing my configuration stored in Azure Appconfiguration. I am using SDK (Azure.Data.AppConfiguration) from Azure function. Following the example from https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration_1.0.2/sdk/appconfiguration/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration/samples/Sample2_HelloWorldExtended.md

I am keep getting 400 error.

Following is my code

```
 var client = new ConfigurationClient(_azureAppConfigurationOptions.ConnectionString);
            
            ConfigurationSetting setting = client.
                                        GetConfigurationSetting(
                                            "appid");
```

the only difference is i am calling from Azure functions.

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you see the 400 error? Could you share the exception or HTTP response?

Comment: can you solve the issue with the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

When try to get configuration(app settings) in azure function, you should use this method `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(xxx)`.

Please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#environment-variables) for details.